# Store Currency code along with price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I am storing a price in my database.

I figured I should store the currency as my application with need to support internationalisation.

I believe the correct way is to store the ISO 4217 currency code, such as USD for US$, AUD for AU$ and EUR for Euros ...

I have a price and a currency attribute in model... Am I doing it right?

How do convert the currency code to it Symbol version? is there a helper for this? do I need to create myself a corresponding hash?

Cheers,

Joel

Comment: I would store the values in one currency, then convert to other currencies as needed.

Comment: @EdManet Really? Apply an exchange rate at the time you use the value? That would return a different price on different days.

Comment: @Widor Exactly.  So in 2009 the price is 1 USD = 1.5 AUD = .7 EUR.  Two years later, when 1 USD = .99 AUD = .8 EUR, should the price still be 1.5 AUD and .7 EUR?  You'd be charging too much AUD and not enough EUR.

Comment: I figured I should store the locale (I18n) rather than the currency code. Then number_to_currency(price, :locale => price_locale) helper should do the trick. Now I didn't think of converting from one currency to another as this may be quite a tricky. hmm I am still a little uncertain but I bet that storing the locale is a more accurate path

Comment: @EdManet That's crazy. Unless this is a financial exchange, you don't want to set a laptop price at, say, 999.99 USD but have your UK visitors see 632.68 GBP today, 632.67 GBP tomorrow but 604.52 back in August? Meanwhile, it's been $999.99 the whole time.

Comment: @Widor isn't it the way works when you buy a laptop out of, let's say eBay? I'll check it out now, but I suppose the price will vary indeed from UK visitors, but I am not sure if it's wrong... is it?

Comment: @joelmaranhao The eBay example is different - that's just showing you a currency conversion to your local currency. What I imagine you are doing is storing a price for various locales, e.g. Apple have a different price for an iPod in all the countries they sell them. They don't just set one price in USD and convert it every time someone buys one in another location.

Comment: @Widor Good point! I suppose what I am implementing is more like an eBay sort of logic. Thanks guys. Now I am trying to figure out whether to choose Money gem suggestion. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the Money gem.  Handles currency codes and has support for exchange rates and formatting.

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

Comment: I like this gem. I wonder if I should just store the locale at the time of the price is stored and then use the Money gem to convert the price ... Today I am handling the formatting via I18n ... thanks for the gem

Comment: in your opinion, would it better to store the locale or the currency code? I suppose it's a matter of choice. Any experience with that?

Comment: Hi jdc, would have any clew to give me on this related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988882/setting-currency-with-form-select-with-money-gem